# Spec for async functions using Jasmine

Tags: underscore.js, jasmine

When I'm trying to test [_.debounce function](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L655) like in [this qunit test](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/test/functions.js#L193) using jasmine something strange happens.

Seems like it could be tested using `jasmine.Clock.useMock()`...
But when I write:

```js
it('_.debounce()', function () {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('debounce'),
        debouncedSpy = _.debounce(spy, 100);

    jasmine.Clock.useMock();

    // direct calls
    debouncedSpy();
    debouncedSpy();
    debouncedSpy();

    // timed out calls
    setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 60);
    setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 120);
    setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 180);
    setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 240);
    setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 300);

    jasmine.Clock.tick(300);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    jasmine.Clock.tick(400);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    jasmine.Clock.tick(1000);
    expect(spy.callCount).toBe(1);
});
```

It doesn't work (call count is equal 3). But without direct calls (or when I'm using `setTimeout(..., 0)`) everything works fine. What I'm doing wrong?

Also I've try to do it through `runs` and `waits`, and it works. But why it doesn't work in previous example?

```js
it('should be called once', function () {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('debounce'),
        debouncedSpy = _.debounce(spy, 100);

    runs(function () {
        debouncedSpy();
        debouncedSpy();
        debouncedSpy();

        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 60);
        setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 120);
        setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 180);
        setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 240);
        setTimeout(debouncedSpy, 300);
    });

    waits(800);

    runs(function () {
        expect(spy.callCount).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at their test on QUnit. And also for the function description. It should be equal `1`, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Until https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/361 and https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/455.  are released, you add this to your tests to have Jasmine skip the debounce delay.

```
_.debounce = function (func) { return function () { func.apply(this, arguments);}; };
```

Answer (score 2):

The jasmine mock clock only changes the behavior of `setTimeout` and it's ilk, it currently doesn't mock out `Date` see https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/361 and https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/455. Using `runs` and `waitsFor` (or in jasmine 2.0 `done` callbacks), actually lets the time pass so the browser actually changes the `Date` value so the date math that happens inside `debounce` adds up.