# Angular Karma Unit Testing Controller Not Injecting Mocked Service Dependency

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I have tried various ways of instantiating the mocked service 'listFilterManager' and passing this to the controller. Although the mocked service is created and accessible, when the scope.$digest() is executed, the actual non-mocked service runs instead of the mocked listFilterManager. Even more confusing is that the resourceStore service is properly mocked and injected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant code:

```
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('listModule');
        module(function($provide){
            $provide.factory('resourceStore', function(){
                return {
                    alertsArray: Object.keys(mockData).map(function(key){
                        return mockData[key];
                    })
                };
            });
            $provide.value('listFilterManager',{
                filterList: jasmine.createSpy('filterList').and.callFake(function(input){
                    return input;
                })
            });
        });
    });

    describe('instantiates the Alert List Ctrl', function(){
        var scope, listFilterParams, listFilterManager, resourceStore, tableAccessorDictionaries, AlertListCtrl;
        beforeEach(function(){
            inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller, _tableAccessorDictionaries_, _listFilterParams_, _resourceStore_, _listFilterManager_){
                scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                listFilterParams = _listFilterParams_;
                listFilterManager = _listFilterManager_; //this refs the mocked service, but the actual service is the one that is executed.
                var deps = {
                    '$scope': scope,
                    'tableAccessorDictionaries': _tableAccessorDictionaries_,
                    'listFilterManager': _listFilterManager_,
                    'listFilterParams': _listFilterParams_,
                    'resourceStore': _resourceStore_
                };
                AlertListCtrl = $controller('AlertListCtrl', deps);
            });
        });

        it('it should filter the list when a list filter parameter changes', function(){
            expect(listFilterManager.filterList).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
            scope.filterParams.text = 'This is a test query';
            scope.$digest();
            expect(listFilterManager.filterList).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that 'listFilterManager' is a service but in the beforeEach method, you are providing it as a value. You need to provide it as a factory in order for it to be properly mocked. Replace the following

```
               $provide.value('listFilterManager',{
            filterList: jasmine.createSpy('filterList').and.callFake(function(input){
                return input;
            })
        });
```

with:

```
               $provide.factory('listFilterManager', function () {
                 return {
                   filterList: jasmine.createSpy('filterList').and.callFake(function(input){
                     return input;
                 };
               })
        });
```

and it should work properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I said I had tried 'various ways', that was one of them. I just plugged it in again to see but no dice, it still calls the real service not the mocked one. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Optionally, have you tried removing the line `listFilterManager = _listFilterManager_;`? Pretty sure once you $provide a service, you don't have to then inject it directly into the controller. For example, if you had mocked all the dependencies of a controller and $provided them, you could init the controller with `myController = $controller('myController', {})`

Comment: no luck. the variable listFilterManager does reference the mocked service, FYI, the issue is just that the controller itself seems to always use the real service. I just tried your suggestion of mocking everything and then not explicitly injecting, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I figured it out. The issue was because the function I was testing was called from within an underscore.debounce wrapper. Debounce apparently causes testing issues, as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707047/spec-for-async-functions-using-jasmine) . The solution is to redefine _.debounce within the test file as such (credit to the aforementioned post):

```
_.debounce = function (func) { return function () { func.apply(this, arguments);}; };
```

Whew, what a frustrating issue, but hopefully this will help someone else in need!